# Program crash on memset?

Tags: c, pointers, memset

I am struggling with `memset`.

If I write in my array my program crashes. If I comment out the `memset` i have no problems.

My type struct:

```
typedef struct  
{
    char Frage  [maxLEN_F_A];
    char Antwort[maxLEN_F_A];
} Fragenfeld;
```

My declaration of the struct:

```
Fragenfeld QuizFragen[maxFragen];
Fragenfeld *ptrQuizFragen = QuizFragen;
```

The `memset` call:

```
memset(&ptrQuizFragen,0,maxFragen*sizeof(Fragenfeld));
```

My function, where I edit the value of the adress:

```
int Fragen_einlesen(Fragenfeld *Quizfragen)
{
....
strncpy(Quizfragen->Frage,sEingabe, maxLEN_F_A);
}
```

Comment: `&ptrQuizFragen` should be just `ptrQuizFragen`. Think about that for a minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
memset(&ptrQuizFragen,0,maxFragen*sizeof(Fragenfeld));
```

you're saying "please set a lot of of bytes, *starting at the address of the pointer variable `ptrQuizFragen`*, to zero." Notice that this is different than saying "please set a lot of bytes, *starting at the beginning of the array pointed at by `ptrQuizFragen`*, to zero." This means the bytes are getting written to the wrong place, which is what's causing your segfault.

Graphically, the setup looks something like this:

```
ptrQuizFragen
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
      |
      v
+-----------+-----------+-----------+ ... +-----------+
|           |           |           |     |           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+ ... +-----------+
QuizFragen
```

The line you've written puts the bytes starting where `ptrQuizFragen` is located in memory, which does this:

```
ptrQuizFragen
+-----------+
| 00000000000000000000000000000000000 ... 000000000000 (oops!)
+-----------+
       
       
+-----------+-----------+-----------+ ... +-----------+
|           |           |           |     |           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+ ... +-----------+
QuizFragen
```

The line you want is

```
memset(ptrQuizFragen, 0, maxFragen * sizeof(Fragenfeld));
```

which says to put the bytes at the memory location pointed at by `ptrQuizFragen`. That would do this:

```
ptrQuizFragen
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
      |
      v
+-----------+-----------+-----------+ ... +-----------+
| 000000000 | 000000000 | 000000000 |     | 000000000 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+ ... +-----------+
QuizFragen
```

Comment: I love your graphical illustration of what's happening.

Comment: :)for this very helpfull answer!

Answer (score 3):

This ...

> ```
> memset(&ptrQuizFragen,0,maxFragen*sizeof(Fragenfeld));
> ```

... requests that the memory starting at the address of variable `ptrQuizFragen` be written, but what you want is that memory at the location to which the pointer points is written:

```
 memset(ptrQuizFragen, 0, maxFragen*sizeof(Fragenfeld));
```

Alternatively, for the same reason that you can initialize `ptrQuizFragen` as you do, you could also do away with it altogether:

```
memset(QuizFragen, 0, maxFragen*sizeof(Fragenfeld));
```

Additionally, it would be clearer to express the wanted size directly in terms of the object being written to:

```
memset(QuizFragen, 0, sizeof(QuizFragen));
```

However, if this is for one-time initialization then I would not use `memset` at all:

```
Fragenfeld QuizFragen[maxFragen] = {0};
```

Although that's valid C with well-defined sematics, some compilers may warn.  If yours does, and that makes you uncomfortable, then one alternative would be to expand a bit to

```
Fragenfeld QuizFragen[maxFragen] = { { {0}, {0} } };
```